# How are linked files labelled in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a project that contains a file that was added as a link.  This file is coming from another project in the same solution.  The link is just pointing to the disk path.

My question is When I take a snapshot of the project in TFS by creating a label, will this file and it's current state be included in the snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

A linked file is nothing more than a reference in a proj file. TFS doesn't know or care that it's a linked file. There's one copy of the file. If you're creating a label at the team project root, then no, files in other team projects won't be included.